# Traceback (most recent call last) when using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import *

a = array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

print(a)
```

The above code showing error after installing `numpy` . The error is:

> C:\Users\91875\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:/Users/91875/PycharmProjects/untitled/numpytest.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/91875/PycharmProjects/untitled/numpytest.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from numpy import *   File "C:\Users\91875\PycharmProjects\untitled\numpy.py", line 3, in
>   
>       a = array([1,2,3]) NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: i am not able to resolve the error please help me to resolve this out

Comment: Rename your file called `numpy.py`.  And use the standard `import numpy as np` expression.

Comment: Thak you i have checked its working but still confused.import numpy as np  but what is the problem with from numpy import * . As per my knowledge both have same meaning and the only difference is that in expression we have to use the name np but in from numpy import * ,we can directly use the array.

Comment: The `*` import is allowed, and works most of the time.  But some functions shadow builtin ones (like `np.sum`).  And it's easier to identify `numpy` use, as with `np.array()` versus `array(...)`.  At some level it's just a matter of style, but you'll see that almost all `numpy` answers use `np...`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you rename your file from `numpy` to say `script.py` it should work

```
from numpy import *

a = array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

print(a)
#[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

But as the other commenters have noted, a more preferred version is to do

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

print(a)
```

One reason behind this is you have [numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and python builtin [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)
, the above notation helps you differentiate between the two like so

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

#Using numpy sum to calculate sum of array
print(np.sum(a))

#Use python builtin sum to calculate sum of array
print(sum(a))
```